# Inference and Simple Gaussian Mixture

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, conditional-expectation, bayesian

I am stuck with the following question. I would be grateful for any help. Assume, we have a simple Gaussian mixture:
\begin{align}
\text{with prob. } \pi: y &=\mu+\epsilon\\
\text{with prob. } 1-\pi: y &= \epsilon
\end{align}
I have a prior $\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0, \sigma_0^2)$ and I know that $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. I observe just one observation $y_1$. I would like to write down a conditional posterior expectation $\mathrm{E}[\mu \vert y_1]$ (and corresponding density $p(\mu \vert y_1)$) in two cases: (1) when I know $\pi$ and (2) when I don't know $\pi$ and only have uniform prior on it $\pi \sim U[0,1]$.

For the first case, I think, we should have $\mathrm{E}[\mu\vert y_1]=\pi \left(\mu_0 + \frac{\sigma_0^2}{\sigma_0^2 + \sigma^2}(y_1-\mu_0)\right)+(1-\pi)\mu_0$, while for the second case, this is $\mathrm{E}[\mu\vert y_1]=\int_0^1 \left[\pi \left(\mu_0 + \frac{\sigma_0^2}{\sigma_0^2 + \sigma^2}(y_1-\mu_0)\right)+(1-\pi)\mu_0\right] \, \mathrm{d}\pi$.

Are my calculations correct? What confuses me is that observation $y_1$ is not used in any way to update prior on $\pi$ in the second case. Shouldn't $y_1$ help learning something both about $\mu$ and $\pi$?

Comment: The first question gives $\mathbb{E}[\mu|y_{1},\pi]$, by law of iterated expectation, the second case should be the integration of $\mathbb{E}[\mu|y_{1},\pi]$ with respect to the conditional probability $p(\pi|y_{1})$, instead of $p(\pi)\equiv 1$.

Comment: @Q9y5 any thoughts on how to derive conditional density $p(\pi \vert y_1)$? -- I am a bit confused how to derive it. For instance, my likelihood is $p(y_1 \vert \pi)$ which is a mixture of 2 Gaussians, but how can I derive it if I do not know $\mu$? Same question for $p(y_1)$.

Comment: Is your first result correct though? In the special case of $\sigma=0$, wouldn't any non-zero $y_1 \neq 0$ imply $\mu = y_1$?  This would mean $\forall y_1 \neq 0: E[\mu \mid y_1] = y_1$.  By symmetry of the Gaussians, this also holds when $y_1 = 0$.  Meanwhile, your proposed answer gives $E[\mu \mid y_1] = \pi y_1 + (1-\pi) \mu_0$.

Comment: @antkam hm, do you know where I may be making a mistake? I calculate $E[\mu \vert y_1]=E[\mu \vert y_1, z=1] Pr[z=1] + E[\mu \vert y_1, z=0] Pr[z=0]$ where $z=1$ when we take the first Gaussian. $E[\mu \vert y_1, z=1]$ is just a posterior expectation and it is $\mu_0 + (y_1 - \mu_0) \frac{\sigma_0^2}{\sigma_0^2+\sigma^2}$ the other one is just expectation of the prior -- $\mu_0$.

Comment: Shouldn't the formula be $E[\mu \vert y_1]=E[\mu \vert y_1, z=1] Pr[z=1\color{red}{\mid y_1}] + E[\mu \vert y_1, z=0] Pr[z=0\color{red}{\mid y_1}]$?  Everything needs to conditioned on $y_1$.